# Chrome extension - Sync data between dexie.js and firebase

Tags: vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-chrome-extension, dexie

I'm using dexie.js in a vue powered chrome extension. I need to store some informations about the items available in a warehouse. Since dexie will not perist data if browser data are cleared, I'm thinking to use it with firebase RTDB. Is this implementation possible, and how I can sync the data between the two databases?

If this syncing isn't reilable, what can be an alternative solution that will be not subject to browser data cleaning?